# tokenizing wide string using boost

Tags: c++, boost, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I'm tokenizing a wide string using boost but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;
vector<wchar_t> vDep;
vector<wchar_t> vArr;
TStringList *slDep;
TStringList *slArr;
wchar_t *chDep;
wchar_t *chArr;
int sz=0;
for (int i = 0; i < mDep->Lines->Count; i++) {
    chDep=WideString(mDep->Lines->Strings[i]).c_bstr();
    ShowMessage(chDep);
    boost::split(vDep,chDep,boost::is_any_of(std::wstring((wchar_t*)" ")));
    sz=vDep.size();
    for (int j = 0; j < vDep.size(); j++) {
        ShowMessage(vDep[j]);
    }
}
```

I'd like to see a working example on tokenizing wide string.

Is boost an optimal choice to tokenize wide string, or is there any other?

Comment: "It's not working" is not a good problem description.

Comment: it shows exception `Assertion failed: !is_singular() ../boost/range/iteratorator_range.hpp`

Comment: Also, instead of casting `" "` to wchar_t*, use a wide string literal, `L" "` .

Comment: it's because i use `std::wstring()` instead of `std::string()` in `is_any_of()`

Comment: Yes, for a wide string, use a wide literal.

Comment: using `L` but the same error!

Answer (score 4):

Change the target to `std::vector<std::wstring>`, and change the source to `std::wstring`, and the delimiter could be a plain wide-string literal;

```
std::vector<std::wstring> target;
std::wstring source = ...;
boost::split(target, source, boost::is_any_of(L" ")));
```

Comment: the following code `using namespace std;
 vector<std::wstring> vDep;
 std::wstring chDep=UnicodeString("asdf asdf asdf ").w_str();
 boost::split(vDep,chDep,boost::is_any_of(L" "));` won't compile !

Comment: this is the error `Assertion failed: !is_singular() ../boost/range/iteratorator_range.hpp`